# Odoo Migration v13 to v16: Snippet Options => UncaughtPromiseError $snippet[0] undefined

Tags: javascript, xml, odoo, code-snippets, odoo-16

In my custom module src/user/tm_web_snip_font_zsb, i have created many custom snippets. One of them is "snippets_numbers_on_vline" and has a sidebar-option to make the number of Timelines Nodes selectable by the user (in webeditor). Even if odoo v16 provide a similar feature now for this, i take this custom module as example. This feature is working perfectly in odoo v13 but in odoo v16, after having drag-and-droped the snippet in a webpage, the option is displayed but when i click on it, i get this error:

```
UncaughtPromiseError > TypeError

Promesse non interceptée > $snippet[0] is undefined

..._createSnippetEditor:function($snippet){var self=this;var snippetEditor=$snippet.data('snippet-editor');if(snippetEditor){return snippetEditor.__isStarted;}
```

[image]
[image]

I have already changed the assets declaration in the v16-way in the `__manifest__.py` file:

```py
    'assets': {
        'website.assets_wysiwyg': ['/tm_web_snip_font_zsb/static/src/js/vline_xnodes.js',  ],
    }
```

```xml
<template id="snippet_numbers_on_vline" inherit_id="website.snippets">
        <xpath expr="//div[@id='snippet_structure']/div[hasclass('o_panel_header')]" position="before">
                     
            <!-- Numbered v-Line -->
            <t t-snippet="tm_web_snip_font_zsb.numbers_on_vline"
               t-thumbnail="/tm_web_snip_font_zsb/static/src/img/snippets/snippets_icon/s_latest_posts.jpg"/>
    

            </div>
        </xpath>
</template>
```

```xml
   <!--===================== s:Numbered v-Line =====================-->
<template id="numbers_on_vline" name="Numbered v-Line">
        <section class="vline_nodes pt32 pb32">
            <div class="container">

<div class="r t-rec t-rec_pt_75 t-rec_pb_75 r_anim r_showed mx-auto" style="padding:75px 0px; max-width:760px;" data-record-type="550"><!-- vline -->
<div class="vline">
<div class="vline_nodes_container t-container">
    <div class="vline_col t-col t-col_8">
        <div class="vline_numberwrapper t-cell t-valign_top" style="padding-bottom:40px;">
            <div class="vline_number">
             <div class="vline_circle" style=" border-width: 2px; background: #fb7c25;"></div>
             <div class="vline_digit t-name t-name_md" style="color:#fff">1</div>
            </div>
            <div class="vline_line" style="width: 2px;background: #bababa;"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="vline_textwrapper t-cell t-valign_top" style="padding-bottom:40px;">
            <div class="vline_title t-name t-name_lg" style="font-size:28px;"><h3 >Théorie</h3></div>
            <div class="vline_descr t-text t-text_xs" style="font-size:18px;">
                <p >We are a leading firm in providing quality and value to our customers...</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!-- vline_col -->
    <div class="vline_col t-col t-col_8">
        <div class="vline_numberwrapper t-cell t-valign_top" style="padding-bottom:40px;">
            <div class="vline_number">
             <div class="vline_circle" style=" border-width: 2px; background: #fb7c25;"></div>
             <div class="vline_digit t-name t-name_md" style="color:#fff">2</div>
            </div>
            <div class="vline_line" style="width: 2px;background: #bababa;"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="vline_textwrapper t-cell t-valign_top" style="padding-bottom:40px;">
            <div class="vline_title t-name t-name_lg" style="font-size:28px;"><h3 >Pratique</h3></div>
            <div class="vline_descr t-text t-text_xs" style="font-size:18px;">
                 <p > We are a leading firm in providing quality and value... </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!-- vline_col -->
    </div><!-- vline_col -->
</div><!-- t-container -->
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div><!-- vline -->
</div><!-- trec -->
            </div> <!-- container -->
        </section>
    </template>
    <!--======================= e:Numbered v-Line ==================-->
```

...and i have already changed the inherit_id of my custom snippet-option-template to fit odoo 16 requirements (inherit_id="website.snippet_options"), just like in the standard snippets of addons/website in odoo v16:

```xml
       <template id="xnodesnum_vline_options" inherit_id="website.snippet_options">
        <xpath expr="." position="inside">
            <div data-js="vline_xnodes"
                    data-selector=".vline_nodes"
                    data-target=".vline_nodes_container">

                <we-select string="Nb vline-nodes">
                        <we-button data-select-count="3">3</we-button>
                        <we-button data-select-count="4">4</we-button>
                        <we-button data-select-count="5">5</we-button>
                        <we-button data-select-count="6">6</we-button>
                        <we-button data-select-count="7">7</we-button>
                        <we-button data-select-count="8">8</we-button>
                    </we-select>
             </div>
        </xpath>
    </template>
```

...and i have adapted my js file (vline_xnodes.js) to Odoo v16 standards too:

```js
odoo.define('tm_web_snip_font_zsb.vline_xnodes', function (require) {
'use strict';

var core = require('web.core');
var Dialog = require('web.Dialog');
var weWidgets = require('wysiwyg.widgets');
var options = require('web_editor.snippets.options');

var _t = core._t;
var qweb = core.qweb;

options.registry.vline_xnodes = options.Class.extend({

    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Options
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Changes the number of vline_nodes.
     *
     * @see this.selectClass for parameters
     */
    selectCount: function (previewMode, value, $opt) {
        this._updateVline_nodeCount(value - this.$target.children().length);
    },

    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Private
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Adds new vline_nodes which are clones of the last vline_node or removes the
     * last x vline_nodes.
     *
     * @private
     * @param {integer} count - positif to add, negative to remove
     */
    _updateVline_nodeCount: function (count) {
        if (!count) {
            return;
        }

        this.trigger_up('request_history_undo_record', {$target: this.$target});

        var vnodesLength = this.$target.children().length + count;
        if (count > 0) {
            var $lastVline_node = this.$target.children().last();
            for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                this.trigger_up('clone_snippet', {$snippet: $lastVline_node});
            }
        } else {
            var self = this;
            _.each(this.$target.children().slice(count), function (el) {
                self.trigger_up('remove_snippet', {$snippet: $(el)});
            });
        }

        var $vnodes = this.$target.children();
        vnodesLength = vnodesLength || $vnodes.length;
        this.vnodesLength = vnodesLength;
        this.trigger_up('cover_update');
    },

    /**
     * @override
     */
    _setActive: function () {
        this._super.apply(this, arguments);
        this.$el.find('[data-select-count]').removeClass('active')
            .filter('[data-select-count=' + (this.vnodesLength || this.$target.children().length) + ']').addClass('active');
    },
});


});
```

But the issue remains nevertheless...